# Ant path style patterns

Tags: java, path, ant, pattern-matching

What are the rules for **Ant path style patterns**.

The Ant site itself is surprisingly uninformative.

Comment: May be this answer would also be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/40886239/355438

Answer (score 218):

Ant-style path patterns matching in [spring-framework](/questions/tagged/spring-framework):

> The mapping matches URLs using the following rules:
>
> - `?` matches one character
> - `*` matches zero or more characters
> - `**` matches zero or more 'directories' in a path
> - `{spring:[a-z]+}` matches the regexp `[a-z]+` as a path variable named "spring"
>
> Some examples:
>
> - `com/t?st.jsp` - matches com/test.jsp but also `com/tast.jsp` or `com/txst.jsp`
> - `com/*.jsp` - matches all `.jsp` files in the `com` directory
> - `com/**/test.jsp` - matches all `test.jsp` files underneath the `com` path
> - `org/springframework/**/*.jsp` - matches all `.jsp` files underneath the `org/springframework path`
> - `org/**/servlet/bla.jsp` - matches `org/springframework/servlet/bla.jsp` but also `org/springframework/testing/servlet/bla.jsp` and `org/servlet/bla.jsp`
> - `com/{filename:\\w+}.jsp` will match `com/test.jsp` and assign the value `test` to the `filename` variable

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

Comment: is there any way to match multiple patterns within one ant expression? like /com/*, /com/**/test.jsp in the same expression?

Comment: This pattern /WEB-INF/tiles-config/*-tiles-definition.xml  to take all the files ends with -tiles-definition.xml is not working for me but at the same time /WEB-INF/tiles-config/*.xml works. So is * matches zero or more characters correct?

Comment: the explanation within the `spring-framework-reference` nicely puts it into a context:
[https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates).

Comment: @chrismarx The comma separated syntax in your example works in Jenkins create-zip-file step which also uses Ant-style pattern to specify its globs.

Comment: In addition, you can use `{*varname}` to match zero or more directories and assign that to the `varname` variable (though this seems to be specific to Spring)

Answer (score 48):

I suppose you mean how to use [path patterns](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns)

If it is about whether to use slashes or backslashes these will be translated to path-separators on the platform used during execution-time.

Comment: +1. As an addition, here is how to navigating to this part of documentation from the Ant Manual: **[Table of Contents](https://ant.apache.org/manual/) => "Concepts and Types" => [List of Types] left menu section => "Directory-based Tasks" => [Patterns] page section**.

Answer (score 14):

**Most upvoted answer** by `@user11153` using tables for a more readable format.

---

The mapping matches URLs using the following rules:

```
+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Wildcard        |            Description                                  |
+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| ?               | Matches exactly one character.                          |
| *               | Matches zero or more characters.                        |
| **              | Matches zero or more 'directories' in a path            |
| {spring:[a-z]+} | Matches regExp [a-z]+ as a path variable named "spring" |
+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Some examples:

```
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Example                      | Matches:                                               |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| com/t?st.jsp                 | com/test.jsp but also com/tast.jsp or com/txst.jsp     |
| com/*.jsp                    | All .jsp files in the com directory                    |
| com/**/test.jsp              | All test.jsp files underneath the com path             |
| org/springframework/**/*.jsp | All .jsp files underneath the org/springframework path |
| org/**/servlet/bla.jsp       | org/springframework/servlet/bla.jsp                    |
|                       also:  | org/springframework/testing/servlet/bla.jsp            |
|                       also:  | org/servlet/bla.jsp                                    |
| com/{filename:\\w+}.jsp      | com/test.jsp & assign value test to filename variable  |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 9):

[ANT Style Pattern Matcher](https://github.com/Mach-II/Mach-II-Framework/wiki/ANT-Style-Pattern-Matcher#Wildcards)

## Wildcards

The utility uses three different wildcards.

```
+----------+-----------------------------------+
| Wildcard |            Description            |
+----------+-----------------------------------+
| *        | Matches zero or more characters.  |
| ?        | Matches exactly one character.    |
| **       | Matches zero or more directories. |
+----------+-----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

As @user11153 mentioned, Spring's [AntPathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) implements and documents the basics of Ant-style path pattern matching.

In addition, Java 7's nio APIs added some built in support for basic pattern matching via [FileSystem.getPathMatcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String))