# Servlet authentication using Shiro, Is it possible to filter URLs having some keyword?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ant, shiro

I have a servlet application running in tomcat with shiro authentication. 
My servlet URL looks like this

```
 http://builds/Query/User?which_option=ui_data&which_out=json
```

The  ***"which_option"*** in the above URL can take various values.
I want to authenticate only those URLs having ***"which_option=ui_data"*** in shiro.
I tried the following using regex in URL filtering in my shiro.ini.

```
[urls]
/Query/User*ui_data* = authcBuilds
```

But that does not work. The [Shiro URL configuration](http://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-%7B%7B%5Curls%5C%7D%7D) page mentions that the URL expression must of *URL_Ant_Path_Expression*. The [ANT path expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952196/learning-ant-path-style) seems to apply for matching only file names, and not part of URL string.

Is there any other way to do this (URL regex matching)? or else I have to shift my code to another servlet like

```
http://builds/Query/UI_Data
```

and use the following authentication in shiro.ini

```
[urls]
/Query/UI_Data* = authcBuilds
```

Answer (score 1):

Shiro's implementation of AntMacher org.apache.shiro.util.AntMatcher does match your URL as required.

```
import org.apache.shiro.util.AntPathMatcher;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class AntMatcherTest {

    @Test
    public void match() {
        final AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();

        assertTrue(matcher.match("/Query/User*ui_data*", "/Query/User?which_option=ui_data"));
    }

    @Test
    public void noMatch() {
        final AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();

        assertFalse(matcher.match("/Query/User*ui_data*", "/Query/User?which_option="));
    }
}
```

Shiro's implementation of javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest splits the URL into parts: Everything *but* the query string goes into the URL which is used in the match. Therefore it won't match query parameters.

Write your own FormAuthenticationFilter and you will have access to the ServletRequest to inspect the query parameters.