# What's the supported URL schema of SprinMVC `getServletMapping()`?

Tags: spring-mvc

According to the JavaDoc for [getServletMapping()](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.html#getServletMappings%28%29):

> Specify the servlet mapping(s) for the DispatcherServlet, e.g. '/',
> '/app', etc.

According to SpringMVC online reference doc, there are 2 ways to specify a URL for `@RequestMapping` annotation:

- [URI templates](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)
- [Ant-style path patterns](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-patterns)

So, does these 2 options apply to `getServletMapping()` as well? Which one is supported by `getServletMapping()`? Or both?

Ref:

- Ant path patterns: [Ant path style patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952196/learning-ant-path-style)
- URI template: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570

Comment: A servlet mapping is a Servlet container configuration. It's (more or less) unrelated to the mapping you specify with `@RequestMapping`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for pointing that out.