# What does 'antMatchers' mean?

Tags: spring-boot

I am learning spring-boot and for my brain, in order to accept some things, it needs to find a meaningful explanation of those things. Could anybody tell me what "ant" in "antMatchers" means? What has an insect like an "ant" got to do with the mapping between a resource and the path of the REST-call?

I know that this is not a language research forum, but I think that developers have also the right to understand or refuse logical/illogical things.

Thank you ;)

Comment: Useful link: [Learning Ant path style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2952196/459391).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It comes from Apache Ant Project, which is a java build system that utilises an xml scripting language. Here is the website [Apache Ant Home](https://ant.apache.org/) and in [Spring Doc for AntPathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) it says "Part of this mapping code has been kindly borrowed from Apache Ant." So "antMatchers" means an implementation of Ant-style path patterns in mappings.

Comment: Thanks @javasenior. Now is my live more supportable.

Comment: You are welcome. If answer is useful, please just upvote so more people which search  the same thing will feel the support :)

Comment: Just a side-note for the Spring developers: `antMatcher` has been an extremely unintuitive naming.

Answer (score 30):

The term comes from the archaic build system, Apache Ant. In Ant paths were matched against a simple pattern containing `*` symbols meaning any string, and `**` meaning 'recursive' descending any number of directories/folders. So, an ant-matcher like this: `/a/b/*/d/**/z` could match: `/a/b/w/d/x/y/z` because the  `w` bit is matched by `*` and the `/x/y/` bit is matched by `**`.

Comment: Thanks @Engineer Dollery. Now is my live more supportable :)

Comment: documentation supports this answer https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html