# jfrog copy directory to another directory

Tags: jfrog-cli

With the `jfrog-cli` I want to copy `"tags/$version"` to `"released/$version"`

`$version` has subdirectories that I need to keep in the respective format.

I tried :

```
jfrog rt cp --flat=false repo/tags/$version/* repo/released/
```

What I get is :

```
repo/released/tags/$version
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: jfrog rt cp --flat=True repo/tags/$version repo/released/$version works.

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory cp/mv is BIZARRE... it does not work like a regular file system move or copy command.

**The following moves (within the same repository) everything including subfolders** from *test/example/libraries/1.0.0* to *test/example/libraries/2.0.0* .

`jfrog rt mv release-local/test/example/libraries/1.0.0 release-local/2.0.0 --user ${userid} --password ${userpwd} --url https://artifactory`

**Before**

```
/test
  /example
    /libraries
       /1.0.0
          file1.dll
          /folder1
             file2.dll
```

**After**

```
/test
  /example
    /libraries
       /2.0.0
          file1.dll
          /folder1
             file2.dll
```

The command appears to take the last element of the path of the target and replace it with the entire path of the source repository *less the last element of the path*... basically it is like a file rename that includes the path as part of the rename. Note that you **do not** have to use the recursive flag or the flat flag for it.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest release of JFrog CLI (version 1.23.1) the command to copy files from one repository to another should be similar to what you have.

For example, if I want to copy all versions from a repository `libs-snapshot-local/` and path `org/jfrog/test/` to a repository called `generic-local` I can execute the command

```
jfrog rt cp libs-snapshot-local/org/jfrog/test/ generic-local/
```

By default, it will recursively copy all items of `libs-snapshot-local/org/jfrog/test/` to their new location in `generic-local`

Answer (score 0):

```
jfrog rt cp --flat=true --recursive=false repo/tags/($version/**) repo/released/{1}
```

or

```
jfrog rt cp --flat=true --recursive=false repo/tags/$version/(**) repo/released/$version/{1}
```

Don't even *try* to get this to work with the (default) `--recursive=true` flag. I've yet to find an instance where that flag does something "useful", interaction with all the other possible flags is just half-baked.

Any naive solution with `--flat=true` **alone** will also fail once you have sub directories to deal with.

Use the Ant-style `**` to glob recursively, and then use the pattern replacement syntax to restore the capture group, building the correct, fully qualified target path.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR (what worked for me):
jfrog rt cp --flat=true --recursive=**true** repo/tags/$version/**(*)** repo/released/$version/{1}

SO

I had been working on this for a bit and all of these solutions had some level of success for me.

For reference, the current version of JFrog Artifactory I'm using is Enterprise 7.59.11 rev 7591190

The solution that gave me the closest thing to success was using the ant-style glob copy function

[Ant-style Wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952196/ant-path-style-patterns):

`?` matches one character

`*` matches zero or more characters

`**` matches zero or more 'directories' in a path

I found that the ant-style `(**)` and matching {1} wildcard matching will result in the following structure:

ex.
`jfrog rt cp --flat=true --recursive=false repo1/test/example/libraries/1.0.0/(**) repo2/2.0.0/{1}`

```html
repo1
  /test
    /example
      /libraries
         /1.0.0
            file1.dll
            /folder1
              file2.dll
```

```html
repo2
  /2.0.0
      file1.dll
      /folder1
        /folder1
          file2.dll
```

**note that each entity within the wildcard match was created on its own, including the directories**

I'm unsure as to why this is the case, but the following settings worked for me:

- `*` zero or more characters wildcard
- flat=true
- recursive=true

`jfrog rt cp --flat=true --recursive=**true** repo/tags/$version/**(*)** repo/released/$version/{1}`