# How to make a controller for all extension type requests?

Tags: spring-boot

Have a spring boot project and a default controller:

```
@Controller
public class GenericController
{
    @RequestMapping(value= {"/**.html", "/"})
    public String httpRequest(Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
```

But works only with /*.html routes. How to catch all .html routes with any folder source? example: `/abc.html`, `/abc/def.html`, `/abc/def/ghi.html`, etc.

I learn about:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#path--
- [Learning Ant path style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952196/learning-ant-path-style)
- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

And try with:

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/**/*.html", "/"})
```

But does not works, when call http://localhost/abc/def/ghi.html returns an http status 404.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do that but you can hack `path params` to do it for you. But its a dirty way and can cause conflicts with other `mappings`.

By using path params like below you can do `/abc.html`, `/abc/def.html`, `/abc/def/ghi.html`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/**.html" , "/{path2}/**.html" ,"/{path}/{path2}/**.html" })
public String httpRequest(Model model) {
    //You can also check which path variables are present and work accordingly 
    System.out.println("index");
    return "index";
}
```

If you want to create a single entry point for your API then I would suggest you to read about [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be using a Filter, that redirects your response according to incoming URI:

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class AFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        if(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()...){ // use regex ?
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

            ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).sendRedirect("/some/path/to/your/thingy");
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

And some controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some/path/to/your/thingy", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Object> aMethod() throws Exception {

    return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
}
```