# Gradle build: Exclude resources files from Spring Boot Jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I would like to exclude all config files from the jar file since they will be provided at the provisioning and having a different version in the build path may create some runtime issues. I am using the following Gradle build script, but for some reason, I can still see whatever exist in the resources directory to be copied into the built Jar. Which means for some reason the provided Gradle build is not working as expected.

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

    distributions {
        main {
            baseName = "${project.name}"
            contents {
                into('/conf'){
                    from('src/main/resources')
                    exclude("application.yml")
                }
                into('/lib'){
                    from('build/libs')
                }
                into('/bin'){
                    from('../bin')
                }
            }
        }
    }


    processResources {
        # Not sure how I need to point to the resources, so I included both. However, none is working.
        exclude('resources/*')
        exclude('src/main/resources/*')
    }

    bootJar{
        # Not sure how I need to point to the resources, so I included both. However, none is working.
        exclude('resources/*')
        exclude('src/main/resources/*')    
    }

    distTar {
        dependsOn bootJar
    }

    tasks.withType(Tar) {
        compression = Compression.GZIP
        extension = "tar.gz"
    }

    configurations {
        customArch
    }

    artifacts {
        customArch file(distTar.archivePath)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to exclude resources from appearing in the Jar file by using `processResources.enabled = false`, so the build file is as follows.

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distributions {
    main {
        baseName = "${project.name}"
        contents {
            into('/conf'){
                from('src/main/resources')
                exclude("application.yml")
            }
            into('/lib'){
                from('build/libs')
            }
            into('/bin'){
                from('../bin')
            }
        }
    }
}

processResources.enabled = false

distTar {
    dependsOn bootJar
}

tasks.withType(Tar) {
    compression = Compression.GZIP
    extension = "tar.gz"
}

configurations {
    customArch
}

artifacts {
    customArch file(distTar.archivePath)
}
```

Comment: Somehow, this doesn't seem to work for me. Doing it like this _does_ cause the `processResources` step to be skipped in the build, but when I check the JAR that was generated, it still contains the file from `src/main/resources`

Answer (score 0):

I found that this solution works for me:

```
processResources {
    exclude('logback-spring.xml')
}
```

...where `logback-spring.xml` is located in `src/main/resources`

Answer (score 0):

Use `bootJar` with [Ant-style path patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952196/ant-path-style-patterns):

```
bootJar {
    exclude('**/logback-spring.xml')
}
```

You *could* also use `processResources`, but then the exclusions would also apply to the build step (i.e., copying to `/build` directory), which may not be inteded.