# Which ANT-style path pattern can catch foo_1.23.456_bar.baz but not foo_1.23.456_qux_bar.baz in a JenkinsFile?

Tags: jenkins, path, ant

The context is a JenkinsFile in which I need to use the `copyArtifacts` function to catch a specific file among all the artifacts of another build. This function uses `ANT-style path pattern`. The build contains several artifacts:

- **foo_1.23.456_bar.baz**
- foo_1.23.456_qux_bar.baz
- foo_1.23.456_thud.baz

And I only want to catch the first one, *without catching another one*. The `1.23.456` part is varying and can contain any set of decimal number (it's a version number).

**What I tried so far**

- `foo_*([0-9]).*([0-9]).*([0-9])_bar.baz`
- `foo_*\.*\.*\._bar.baz`
- `foo_*\\.*\\.*\\._bar.baz`

In all those cases, I either get a Jenkins syntax error, or I don't catch any file at all, or I catch too many of them. I've thoroughly read [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952196/learning-ant-path-style) but this time it didn't help me.

Can someone help me figuring out the correct ANT-style path pattern for this specific usecase ?

Comment: In Ant you would use a general include pattern with a specific exclude pattern, rather than trying to do it in one.  The Copy Artifacts docs say it supports exclude rules - worth looking in to.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer you reference is for Spring Ant paths, which support more patterns than standard Ant paths.   Ant only supports *, **, and ?

Comment: @martinclayton Thank you, I didn't think about using exclude patterns. It works well ! Feel free to turn your first comment into an answer, I'll then upvote & accept it