# What does .+ mean in Path Variable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api

in a Spring Boot REST API Project I came across a Route which was somewhat like this:

```
@DeleteMapping("api/{variable:.+}")
```

What does the .+ stand for?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952196/ant-path-style-patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stands for: one or more characters.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html for reference.